# Copy a range of characters out of an URL

Tags: javascript, url, clipboard

I am a complete starter und just read into javascript, because I would like to copy a certain range of characters of a current URL into the clipboard. In this case the 14th to 6th last characters.

The script should run in Opera.

This is what I tried.

```
javascript:(function()
{
    var L = location.href; 
    LL = L.length; 
    start = LL - 14; 
    end = LL - 6; 
    alert ( LL + ' ' + start + ' ' + end ); 
    L.setSelectionRange(start,end);
    L.execCommand("copy")
})();
```

Just like I would like to copy the numbers out of the current URL:

stackoverflow.com/questions/**35584433**/copy-a-range-of-characters-out-of-an-url

The calculation is correct, alert (for check) returns the correct values, but the character range does not get copied to the clipboard.

Comment: could you explain more?, the function setSelectionRange what does it do exactly? also you want to copy something to the clipboard is that right?

Comment: Ok, sure. The code should be a called via a bookmark (instaed of the URL the java code is executed) to copy the numbers from the current webpage URL to the clipboard. I then click "save as" and hit CTRL-V to put in the copied numbers. Right now I need to mark the numbers manually in the URL and hit CTRL-C to do this.